# Como abrir ficheiro no MS-Office com Javascript ou PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, office-2013

Eu tenho um site que funciona **só** numa rede local, onde tenho vários ficheiros armazenados no servidor da aplicação web, e eu gostaria, de alguma maneira, usar o PHP ou Javascript para abri-lo directamente com o MS-Office, a partir do lado do cliente.

Desta forma eu poderia abrir o ficheiro com a aplicação do Word, e fazer as alterações necessárias e, ao guardar, fazia logo o update no server.

Não sei se é possivel ou não, mas gostaria de saber.

Comment: Já li que, por questões de segurança, não era possível, e também já li métodos em que criam uma nova instancia da classe activeXObject mas não sei.

Comment: Você quer abrir o word no servidor ou no computador do cliente?

Comment: No computador do cliente, eu tentei utilizar o shel_exec(); no PHP mas, como o codigo corre no servidor, o word abre no servidor.

Answer (score 8):

Numa empresa em que trabalhei, certa vez por causa de requisitos de um cliente, uma equipe precisou implementar uma <del>tremenda gambiarra</del> solução de geração de contratos no *client*, mais especificamente, no navegador via Javascript.

## Solução no lado do cliente com ActiveX

Esta solução consistia nos seguintes procedimentos:

1. Abrir um documento template via uma URL no Word
2. Acessar um Web Service REST via Ajax e recuperar dados em formato Json
3. Mesclar os dados com o documento usando alguma magia negra através da API do Word
4. Salvar o documento num local especificado no HD do usuário através da API do Word

Obviamente, só um *grande* <del>(coff! coff!!)</del> browser com o Internet Explorer disponibiliza uma "API" para tudo isso.

Estou falando do [`ActiveXObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). Veja um exemplo básico de como "abrir o word":

```js
var oApplication = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
oApplication.Visible = true; //Deixa o Word no modo invisível
oApplication.Documents.Open("template_contrato.docx");
var oDocument = oApplication.ActiveDocument;
```

A partir daí é possível usar qualquer métodos da [API de Interoperabilidade do Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

## Solução no lado do servidor com ActiveX

Conheci alguns sistemas que implementavam a solução acima em Java no lado do servidor.

O problema é que como a instância do Office no Windows é única, o sistema não suportava chamadas concorrentes.

Além disso, se houvesse qualquer problema a rotina ficava bloqueada e o servidor tinha que ser acessar manualmente, por exemplo, para finalizar a instância do Office que estava com problemas.

Um dos relatos do responsável pela solução era de que o Office frequentemente mostrava caixas de diálogo sobre atualização ou qualquer outra coisa inesperada e isso impedia que o documento continuasse sendo manipulado. A solução era logar remotamente no servidor e clicar no botão do diálogo que travava o servidor.

Resumindo: o Office não foi feito para isso.

## Solução no lado do servidor com manipulação de XML.

O novo formato do Office (a partir do 2007) nada mais é que um ZIP composto de vários arquivos, dentro os quais, os documentos são simplesmente arquivos XML. Daí a extensão terminando com "X" (docx, pptx, xlsx).

Outro projeto que conheci consistia em ter um documento descompactado no servidor. Então, quando o usuário pedia um contrato para um determinado cliente, uma rotina manipulava o arquivo `document.xml` (que fica na pasta `word` da estrutura de arquivos de um documento). Os dados do cliente eram substituídos em locais marcados por "tags" e então a pasta era compactada em um novo DOCX e disponibilizada para o usuário via download.

Veja um pouco sobre a [estrutura de um documento do office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266220%28office.12%29.aspx?info=EXLINK):

[image: Estrutura Interna de um Documento do Office]

Não seria algo tão complexo de implementar em PHP, isto é:

1. Manipulação de XML
2. Compactação de arquivo

Mas espere! Na verdade já existem várias bibliotecas que podem fazer isso:

1. [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) (free)
2. [docxgen](https://github.com/djpate/docxgen) (free)
3. [PHPDOCX](http://www.phpdocx.com/) (paga)

## Conclusão e outras alternativas

Minha recomendação é não fazer isso e considerar as seguintes alternativas:

1. Usar uma segundo linguagem como Java com uma API que não usa o Office, tal como o POI (livre) ou Aspose (pago)
2. Gerar PDF, que o PHP pode gerar nativamente
3. Gerar XLS, que o PHP também consegue gerar
4. Gerar um HTML com extensão "docx", pois o WORD geralmente consegue carregar o arquivo (<del>olha a gambiarra!</del>)

Enfim, sua criatividade é o limite.

Somente tenha consciência que cada escolha tem suas consequências. Algumas terão novas exigências no lado do servidor, outras para o cliente.

Comment: Ou ele pode "fazer" o docx também, compactando todos os arquivos no formato exigido.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Sim, é claro! Como eu pude esquecer...

Comment: @blackblather Abra com o ActiveX, conforme explicado na resposta, e simplesmente mantenha o documento aberto. Você até pode configurar as máquinas dos clientes para receber um comando remoto, porém isso só funcionaria num intranet se não houver um firewall ou proxy no caminho. Outra alternativa é fazer um Java Applet só para isso. Ainda outra alternativa é configurar o browser dos clientes para abrir o word diretamente quando fizer o download do arquivo DOC, assim como ocorre com PDF em alguns casos. Aí você pode apontar para a URL do arquivo e pronto.